# Disable plugin disable notification in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using following to code to disable plugin update notification but it works only if plugin is active, so if I de-active my plugin it start showing update notification. How can I stop this notification even if plugin is not active?

```
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'dd_remove_update_nag');

function dd_remove_update_nag($value) {
unset($value->response[plugin_basename(__FILE__)]);
return $value;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your theme is using TGM plugin activation? Search for class-tgm-plugin-activation in your theme. If it's there, you can disable that notification in the file that controls it.

Comment: @dingo_d No i didn't found this class. Is there any other way like I'm doing  for active plugin? I am developing a plugin and I want this only for my own plugin not for the entire wordpress.

Comment: Sorry, but nothing comes to mind...

Answer (score 0):

For example if you don't want Wordpress to show update notifications for akismet, you will do it like:

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['akismet/akismet.php'] );
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Comment: You can put that in your theme's functions.php if not possible then you can put in a separate plugin file.

Comment: I tried this, but as mentioned in my question, it works only when plugin is active. i want to disable notification also when my plugin is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your child theme funcation.php file

```
// Remove certain plugins
function my_recommended_plugins( $plugins ) {
// Remove notice to install WooCommerce
  unset( $plugins['woocommerce'] );
// Return plugins
    return $plugins;
}

add_filter( 'wpex_recommended_plugins', 'my_recommended_plugins' );
// Remove all plugins
// THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED IF YOU ARE USING SOME OF THE PLUGINS SINCE THE NOTICE IS IS ALSO USED TO LET YOU KNOW OF UPDATES
add_filter( 'wpex_recommended_plugins', '__return_empty_array' );
```

That's it

Comment: "wpex_recommended_plugins" is not a WordPress core filter.